# Accessing user info from a one way trust

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I have two domains, MINE and THEIRS. MINE is my local domain and has a one way trust with THEIRS (using LDAPS port 636), so that MINE trusts THEIRS but THEIRS does not trust MINE. I can add users from THEIRS to groups in MINE, and have users from THEIR log into machines and applications on the MINE network. The trust appears to be working properly.

I am writing a little .Net application (not ASP.Net) to test connectivity over the WAN. We have one app that isn't seeing users from THEIRS in groups in MINE. Other apps, like SharePoint, work fine.

I tried using ASP.Net 4 option with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement objects, like PrincipalContext, UserPrincipal, GroupPrincipal, etc. Quick code snippet

```
    PrincipalContext domainContext = GetDomainContext(DomainName, ConnectionPort,
        UseSpecifiedCredentials, Credentials);

    GroupPrincipal theGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext,
        IdentityType.SamAccountName, GroupName);

    PrincipalCollection theUsers = theGroup.Members;

    var users = from u in theUsers
                select u.Name;

    return users.ToArray();
```

It all works GREAT when I connect directly to MINE. The issue comes in with connecting to THEIRS. Either the 1 way trust of the LDAPS traffic is returning the error:

```
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.
```

So I switch to .Net 2 variations using DirectoryEntry, DirectorySearcher, etc. This actually works against THEIRS domain.

```
    List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
    string searchString = string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", GroupName);
    SearchResult result = SearchAD(DomainName, ConnectionPort, searchString);
```

I can connect directly to the THEIRS domain, using some impersonation in the code.

When I query the groups in MINE, I get back the SID for the users from THEIRS, not a user account.

```
The following users are a member of testGroup:
CN=S-1-5-21-....,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=MINE,DC=local
CN=S-1-5-21-....,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=MINE,DC=local
```

I tried the impersonation on this as well, running it as a user from THEIRS but no luck.

How can I get user info from THEIRS when the user is in MINE? Do I have to take the above CN/SID and query THEIRS domain? What am I missing in the .Net 4 stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your ASP.NET machine running in MINE.

Your System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement approach should just work if you make sure you use a domain user account from THEIR domain to run the application.  In normal one-way trust configuration (unless you are doing selective authentication trust), the domain user account from THEIR should have permissions to read from both MINE and THEIR.

To make sure you use a domain user from THEIR domain, you can simply [set the AppPool identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28WS.10%29.aspx).  Of course, you can use impersonation to do it too.

Comment: I am using a .net client application, and i run impersonation within the code, however I have tried a run as option and select a THEIR user.. I will try that out.

Comment: it appears my impersonation is in fact NOT impersonating the THEIRS user account that i need it to. Going to troubleshoot this first.

Comment: @DavidLozzi Make sure you are calling [LogonUserEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do the impersonation.  If you are doing the impersonation of the logged on user without providing the password, you need to setup your IIS machine to be trusted for delegation.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314172/impersonate-a-user-on-another-domain-one-way-trust for what I'm doing on impersonation. I'll check out LogonUserEx

Comment: If I understand your configuration correctly, you are trying to impersonate a login account and use that login account to do group enumeration.  I suggest you better set a permanent service account in the AppPool to do group enumeration.  This can eliminate a lot of permissions issue down the road.  The problem of using impersonation approach is that you cannot guarantee the guy who just log on has sufficient rights.

Comment: I got impersonation squared away. I'm not using an app pool, this is a .net application, not ASP.Net.